# Stop Gigya log in from directing back to the log in page

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, sap-commerce-cloud, gigya

We are using Gigya as our log in service on our SAP Commerce site.

This is the code that is executed when a user clicks the log in button:

ssoLogin(language: string): void {
gigya.sso.login({
authFlow: "redirect",
context: {
appName: "eCom",
lang: language
},
useChildContext: true
});
}

We have noticed that when the user logs in they are first directed back to the log in page and then to the actual store they are logging in to.

How can we make it so that they're not directed to the log in page but are directed straight to the store?

We have tried changing authFlow from "redirect" to "popup" and we have also tried passing a redirect url in the method call, but neither option stopped gigya from directing the user to the log in page after logging in.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about how Commerce integrated the GConnector, i assume it is related to CLP (Central Login Page (https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CUSTOMER_DATA_CLOUD/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/dd559b36cb4d4c13ae8d36ffa13e34e0.html#central-login-page-(clp))) which is a requirement for supporting browsers that do not support 3rd party cookies, i.e., Safari (and soon Chrome). The user will always need to relay through the CLP in order for SSO to function properly.

That said, Commerce maintains the integration internally, Gigya/CDC is not involved in it.